# Convert the string to Array and process it

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a string like below

`String detail = "UserDetail: Name=TestName1, Address=India, Name=TestName2, Address=USA";`

I want to get only list of names. i.e in above example i want to remove string `UserDetail` and `Address` details and `Name` get a list which has only `TestName1` and `TestName2`.

As of now i am converting the String to `list` and performing a substring/removing the values from the lists.

I was wondering is there any other efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Was it a `json` string?

Comment: If you know your way about regular expressions, use `Pattern`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
String detail = "UserDetail: Name=TestName1, Address=India, Name=TestName2, Address=USA";
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("Name=(\\w+)");
Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(detail);
while (matcher.find())
    result.add(matcher.group(1));
System.out.println(result);
```

result:

```
[TestName1, TestName2]
```

Comment: Looks like this works!! Let me keep this question open for some more time  and see if i get some more solutions. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to do it with String.split(delimiter).
for first call use : as delimiter and the ntake second element of returned array "Name=TestName1, Address=India, Name=TestName2, Address=USA"
then split that on ,(comma)
and then loop through that array and split each element on = and take second element of returned array, which is what you are looking for

Comment: I am doing this. But i am looking for some more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try Pattern:

```
    String pattern = "Name=(\\w+)";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(detail);
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    while (m.find()) {
        result.add(m.group(1));
    }
```